# Can not set "Sharing" in Loki final release

Tags: settings

Everytime I try to open "Sharing" it closes the Settings window. Is there any command to open this page so I can debug the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but today with an update there came a fix for this.
After the update of the package 'switchboard-plug-sharing' it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's helped. I forgot to check update before.

Comment: @iggy If this answered your question, please don't forget to click the check box next to the answer.