# System Settings Sharing

Tags: release-loki, sharing

When Click Sharing in Network & Wireless, system settings to force quit?

Comment: This is not the place to report bugs. Do so here: bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos

Answer (score 1):

Please update your system. This was a bug but it's fixed.
[See here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7567/can-not-set-sharing-in-loki-final-release/7569#7569)

Comment: No idea how you understood what he/she said. +1 just for that.

Comment: =D thx Gabriel. I understood because i had the same behavior of the switchboard-plug-sharing a few days ago and also the question was already asked.  Maybe i interpreted more as i really understand^^   My native language is not english (too).